# how to pass parameters to controler method from xmlrpc server codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, xmlhttprequest, xml-rpc

i am having trouble in passing parameter values from xmlrpc server to controller method which is being called recursively using a cron job .
 my xml rpc server method:

```
function update_p($request) {
        $parameters = $request->output_parameters();

        $_GET["portfolio"] = $parameters['0']["portfolio"];
        $_GET["filter"] = $parameters['0']["filter"];
        $_GET["sort"] = $parameters['0']["sort"];
        $_GET["first"] = $parameters['0']["first"];
        $_GET["watch"] = $parameters['0']["watch"];
        redirect("controllerClass/update_p");

        return 1;
    }
```

my controller class with method to which i want to  pass all these parameters portfolio ,filter etc:

> public function update_p() {
>           $loginid = $this->session->userdata('loginid');
>           if(!isset($loginid)){
>               die;
>           }
>
> ```
>     error_reporting(E_ERROR);
>     if (time()>$this->session->userdata('expire'))
> ```
>
> { redirect("/dashboard/logout?expired=Y","location",401); die; }
>
> ```
>     $out='';
>
>     $request="USER ".$loginid.($this->session->userdata('isMobile')?"@mobile":"")."\n";
>
>     if(isset($_GET["portfolio"])) {
>         $portfolio=trim($_GET["portfolio"]);
>         $request.='ECHO "LISTP":'."\nLISTP0 #".$portfolio;
>         if(isset($_GET["filter"])) {
>             $filter=trim($_GET["filter"]);
>             $request.=" -".$filter;
>         }
>         if(isset($_GET["sort"])) {
>             $sort=trim($_GET["sort"]);
>             if ($sort>=1024) $request.=" -s".($sort&1023);
>             else $request.=" -S".$sort;
>         }
>         $ph = isset($_GET["first"]);
>         if ($ph) { 
>             $this->load->model('modelmethod');
>             $resultArray = $this->modelmethod->getData($this->session->userdata('loginid'),$this->session->userdata('isMobile')?'mobile':'default','listp');
>             $request.=" ".$resultArray[0]['listp'];
>         }
>         $request.="\nECHO ,\n";
>         if(isset($_GET["watch"])) {
>             $portfolio=trim($_GET["watch"]);
>             if ($ph)
>                 $resultArray = $this->modelmethod->getData($this->session->userdata('loginid'),$this->session->userdata('isMobile')?'mobile':'default','watch');
>             $request.='ECHO "watchl":'."\nLISTP1 #".$portfolio." -WL ".($ph?$resultArray[0]['watch']:"")."\n";
>             $request.='ECHO ,"watchs":'."\nLISTP1 #".$portfolio." -WS\nECHO ,\n";
>         }
>     }
>     $request.="RISk\nECHO ,\nPnL\n";
>
>     if ($result=$this->getData($request."BYE\n")) {
>         if (result!='') $out=$result."\n";
>     }
>
>     ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
>     echo "{".$out."}";
>     ob_end_flush();
>
> }
> ```

i am trying to test it using firbug console using this code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://example/api/v1/update_p?");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("portfolio=0&filter=A&sort=1&first=Y");
```

any help would be much appreciated thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:
**EDIT 1:**

```
function update_p($request) {
    $parameters = $request->output_parameters();

    $_GET["portfolio"] = $parameters['0']["portfolio"];
    $_GET["filter"] = $parameters['0']["filter"];
    $_GET["sort"] = $parameters['0']["sort"];
    $_GET["first"] = $parameters['0']["first"];
    $_GET["watch"] = $parameters['0']["watch"];
    //redirect("controllerClass/update_p/".$_GET["portfolio"].'/'.$_GET["filter"].'/'.$_GET["sort"].'/'.$_GET["first"].'/'.$_GET["watch"], 'refresh');
    $url   = base_url("controllerClass/update_p/".$_GET["portfolio"].'/'.$_GET["filter"].'/'.$_GET["sort"].'/'.$_GET["first"].'/'.$_GET["watch"]);
    header("Location: $url");

    return 1;
}
```

**Controller Method**

```
function update_p(){
    $portfolio  = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $filter     = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $sort       = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $first      = $this->uri->segment(6);
    $watch      = $this->uri->segment(7);
}
```

Comment: i tried this method and its breaking my cron job and now it returns 500 internal server error i tried assigning each parameter   values in this format if(isset($this->uri->segment(3))){
       $_GET["portfolio"]  = $this->uri->segment(3);}